# DropDownList control returning null within GridView during casting

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, controls

I am very new to development in asp.net.
What I am TRYING to do is upon edit of a gridrow, provide a drop down list for a particular column.

User story: User enters text into termSearch textbox; A list of items matching the search criteria is returned. The Activity Status column has only 2 valid values; active, inactive.

My problems are as follows:

1. DropDownList/Text not reflected in designer if it is within TemplateField. When outside of TemplateField, designer detects it.
2. During a cast, value is being returned as null.
3. During DataSource method, drop down list (ddlActivity) returning null.

**GridView** (Activity Status Template Field)

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />

    <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Term Code" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="true">
        <ItemStyle Width="24%" />
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="DISPLAYLABEL" HeaderText="Label" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="true">
        <ItemStyle Width="24%" />
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity Status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lblActivity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("STATUS_FK") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActivity" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("STATUS_FK") %>'>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="STRINGATTRIBUTE" HeaderText="String Attribute" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="true">
        <ItemStyle Width="24%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LONGLABEL" HeaderText="Long Label" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="true">
        <ItemStyle Width="24%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void gvSearch_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string code = termSearch.Text;
    ddlActivity.DataSource = termDAO.SearchByCode(code);
    DropDownList ddlActivityStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlActivity");
    ddlActivityStatus.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select a Status--", "0"));
    ddlActivityStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Active", "STATUS.A"));
    ddlActivityStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Inactive", "STATUS.I"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ddlActivity` is in the `EditItemTemplate`. So you have to check for that.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList ddlActivityStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlActivity");
        }
    }
}
```